# Update with subselect in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to make the following statement to work in MySQL?

```
UPDATE my_table t1 SET column_1 = 
(SELECT column_1 FROM my_table t2 WHERE t2.id = (t1.id - 1))
WHERE t1.type = 2
```

I am getting a `"You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause"` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update with a join:

```
UPDATE my_table t1
    JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.id = t1.id - 1
SET t1.column_1 = t2.column_1
WHERE t1.type = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing "my_table" :)

```
UPDATE t1 SET column_1 = 
(SELECT column_1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = (t1.id - 1))
WHERE t1.type = 2
```

Comment: It's the same table in both queries. I want to use the data from the same table, so I use t1 and t2 as aliases.